# Make SVG height smaller in size & full-width?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I have SVG & it is of size 1326 x 745.

SVG looks like:

```
import React from 'react'

export const Wave = (props: React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>) => {
    return (
        <svg viewBox="0 0 16 9" {...props}>
            <path
                d="M0 8L0.2 7.8C0.3 7.7 0.7 7.3 1 7.2C1.3 7 1.7 7 2 6.8C2.3 6.7 2.7 6.3 3 6C3.3 5.7 3.7 5.3 4 5.7C4.3 6 4.7 7 5 7.5C5.3 8 5.7 8 6 7.5C6.3 7 6.7 6 7 5.7C7.3 5.3 7.7 5.7 8 5.8C8.3 6 8.7 6 9 6.2C9.3 6.3 9.7 6.7 10 6.8C10.3 7 10.7 7 11 6.7C11.3 6.3 11.7 5.7 12 5.7C12.3 5.7 12.7 6.3 13 6.5C13.3 6.7 13.7 6.3 14 6.3C14.3 6.3 14.7 6.7 15 6.8C15.3 7 15.7 7 15.8 7L16 7L16 10L15.8 10C15.7 10 15.3 10 15 10C14.7 10 14.3 10 14 10C13.7 10 13.3 10 13 10C12.7 10 12.3 10 12 10C11.7 10 11.3 10 11 10C10.7 10 10.3 10 10 10C9.7 10 9.3 10 9 10C8.7 10 8.3 10 8 10C7.7 10 7.3 10 7 10C6.7 10 6.3 10 6 10C5.7 10 5.3 10 5 10C4.7 10 4.3 10 4 10C3.7 10 3.3 10 3 10C2.7 10 2.3 10 2 10C1.7 10 1.3 10 1 10C0.7 10 0.3 10 0.2 10L0 10Z"
                strokeLinecap="round"
                strokeLinejoin="miter"
                fill="currentColor"
            ></path>
        </svg>
    )
}
```

It takes so much space. I want it to be really small. Only take up wave space.

[image: svg]

I made this Wave SVG on https://app.haikei.app/

I tried all configurations but I can't get it to be small.

All I want is `width` to be `100%` no matter which device I'm on & it should have a proportional height. What do I need to do to change it?

Comment: Try using this viewBox instead : `viewBox="0 5.5 16 4.5"` and no height. If you need the width to be 100% don't use an with attribute either. By default the svg element will take all the width available.

Comment: You seem to have conflicting requests: "I want it to be really small" and also "I want width to be 100% no matter which device I'm on & it should have a proportional height".  Which is it?  Perhaps you could add a picture or two to explain how you want it to behave.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I want a wave that looks decent that is full-width on all devices. I can't get it to be full-width on my 1920x1080 PC. I don't care if it cuts off on smaller devices as long as it covers the whole width.

Comment: @enxaneta it worked. how did you do it? can you explain? also, can you tell me if i can generate a wave that fits what i want using haikei app for creating future SVG waves or literally anything else? and it doesn't remove background completely even though there is a config in haikei to remove it so would love to know how to do that too as i currently use `white` bg on light theme & `black` bg on dark theme to blend the SVG with the background :)

Comment: The haikei site doesn't seem to give you any control over how much of the frame the wave occupies. It always seems to be stuck in one half of the frame.  What @enxaneta's change does is tell the browser to focus on just the wave. The top value is now 5.5 (from the top) and the height is 4.5.  5.5+4.5 adds up to the original 0+9.

Comment: In order to get the values for the new viewBox attribute I'm using javascript and the getBBox() method for the path. This is returnig an object with an x y width and height attributes. You can use those values to build the new viewBox = x y width height.  Read Paul LeBeau comment for an explanation.

Comment: A simple way to create a wave would begin by creating an array of points with increasing values for the x and random values (inside of a certain range) for the y.  Next you can connect those points with bezier curves.